# Haskell data types with type variables

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have been going through tutorial examples for data types and I have defined the following:

```
ghci> data Animal a b = Cat a | Dog b | Rat
ghci> data BreedOfCat = Siamese | Persian | Moggie
ghci> :t Cat Siamese
Cat Siamese :: Animal BreedOfCat b
ghci> :t Cat Persian
Cat Persian :: Animal BreedOfCat b
ghci> :t Dog 12
Dog 12 :: Num b => Animal a b
ghci> :t Dog "Fifo"
Dog "Fifo" :: Animal a String
ghci> :t Rat
Rat :: Animal a b
```

If `Dog "Fifo"` gives `Animal a String`, why doesn't `Dog 12` give `Animal a Integer` (which is what the tutorial says it should)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It basically does. It just does not pick a specific type for the `12`, this can be *any* type that is a member of the `Num` typeclass, hence `Num b => Animal a b`. If you force to pick an `Integer` for `12`, it will, indeed:

```
ghci> :t Dog (12 :: Integer)
Animal a Integer
```

Comment: It's likely the tutorial is both old enough that it was written when the monomorphism restriction was on by default in ghci, and conflating with the case where the value has been assigned to a variable to trigger the monomorphism restriction.